# The difference between 'and' and '&' in Python

Tags: python

I am reviewing the logical operators in Python. What's the difference between the 'and' operator and the '&' operator?

It seems that '&' is doing a bitwise AND, like 10(1010) & 7(0111) result in 2(0010). But how does the 'and' actually work? Why does 10 & 7 result in 7 in this case? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please search before asking…

Comment: `10 & 7` is certainly not `7`.

Comment: PSA: [Wikipedia exists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra).

Comment: @tadman given the correct explanation in the sentence before I assume OP meant `10 and 7`

Comment: @mozway I see that in a correction now.

Comment: The behaviour of the boolean operators is defined here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not. Note that `x and y` is documented as meaning *"if x is false, then x, else y"*: that's why `10 and 7` results in 7.